# Expected value of $E[X_1^2+\dots X_n^2]$

Tags: probability

$n$ randomly throw balls to $n$ urns. Let $X_i$ wil be number of balls in the $i$-th urn. Compute $$E[X_1^2+\dots X_n^2]$$

So I'm trying, but it's tricky for me

$$E[X_1^2+\dots X_n^2] = E[X_1^2]+\dots+E[X_n^2]  = nE[X_i^2] $$

$$E[X_i^2] = \sum_{i=0}^{n} \left(\frac {{n\choose i}(n-i) }{n^n}\right)^2 i$$

But I don't manage to finish it. Help me, please.

Comment: I don’t think you can say $\sum_{i=1}^n E[X_i^2] = n\,E[X_1^2]$, as you have the additional constraint $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i = n$.

Comment: Yes, and this would be only if $X_i$ are iid, which they clearly are not.

Comment: Independence is irrelevant to the expectation of the sum being the sum of the expectations. In the present case, $(X_i)$ is *exchangeable* hence, indeed, $E(X_i^2)=E(X_1^2)$ for every $i$ and $E(X_1^2+\cdots+X_n^2)=nE(X_1^2)$.

Comment: On the other hand, note that the last formula in the post seems to be based on the (wrong) assumption that $$E(X^2)=\sum_iP(X=i)^2i,$$ while, in fact, $$E(X^2)=\sum_iP(X=i)i^2.$$

Comment: Just to clarify, you have $n$ urns AND $n$ balls being thrown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$X_i$ have the same binomial distribution with parameters $p=\frac{1}{n}$ and $n,$ because one ball can drop in to $i-$th urn with probability $\frac{1}{n}$ or other urn with probability $\frac{n-1}{n}.$ Now, You can easy compute $\mathbb{E}X_i^2=\mathbb{D}^2 X_i+(\mathbb{E}X_i)^2=n \frac{1}{n} \frac{n-1}{n}+(n \frac{1}{n})^2=2-\frac{1}{n}.$

$X_i$ are not independent but do not mind. The property $\mathbb{E}(X_1+\ldots+X_n)=\mathbb{E}X_1+\ldots+\mathbb{E}X_n$ is true for any integrable random variables $X_i.$

Comment: What is $\mathbb{D}^2X_i$

Comment: $\mathbb{D}^2 X_i$ is a variance of random variable $X_i.$

Comment: Are you sure of your solution ?

Comment: Yes, I think this is correct solution.

Comment: @xaweyNEW by linearity of expectation, Rafal's answer is correct (+1). You just need to do the sum: to see that $E[X_1^2+\dots X_n^2] = 2n-1$

Answer (score 1):

You have $n$ balls in $n$ throws.

1. If you have $k_1,k_2,\cdots,k_n$ balls in the urns the number of ways of having that configuration is (see **note 1**):
   $${n \choose k_1}{n-k_1 \choose k_2}\cdots {n-k_1-\cdots-k_{n-2} \choose k_{n-1}}{n-k_1-\cdots-k_{n-1} \choose k_n}=\frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!\cdots k_n!}$$
2. The total number of configurations is $n^n$ (you have $n$ options for each one of the $n$ balls)

Then the probability of having a $k_1,\cdots,k_n$ balls is:

$$\mathbb{P}(X_1=k_1,\cdots,X_n=k_n)=\frac{1}{n^n}\frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!\cdots k_n!}$$

Then:

$$\mathbb{E}(X_1^2+X_2^2+\cdots+X_n^2)=\mathbb{E}\left((X_1+\cdots+X_n)^2-\sum_{i \neq j} X_iX_j\right)$$
$$=n^2-\sum_{i \neq j}\mathbb{E}\left( X_iX_j\right)$$

The cross expectations are (see **note 2**):

$$\mathbb{E}(X_iX_j)=\sum_{k_1+k_2+...+k_n=n} k_i k_j  \frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!\cdots k_n!}\frac{1}{n^n}=\frac{n-1}{n}$$

How the terms with $i \neq j $ are $n^2-n$:

$$\mathbb{E}(X_1^2+X_2^2+\cdots+X_n^2)=n^2-(n^2-n)\frac{n-1}{n}=2n-1$$

> **Note 1**
>
> We have to choose $k_1$ balls from $n$ balls to be put in the urn $1$
>   then you have ${n \choose k_1}$ ways of doing it.
>
> We have to choose $k_2$ balls from $n-k_1$ balls to be put in the urn
>   $2$ then you have ${n \choose k_1}$ ways of doing it.
>
> We have to choose $k_n$ balls from $n-k_1-\cdots-k_{n-1}$ balls to be
>   put in the urn $n$ then you have ${n-k_1-\cdots-k_{n-1} \choose k_n}$
>   ways of doing it.
>
> Then the configuration have a total number of doing it of:
>
> $${n \choose k_1}{n-k_1 \choose k_2}\cdots {n-k_1-\cdots-k_{n-2}\choose k_{n-1}}{n-k_1-\cdots-k_{n-1} \choose k_n}$$
>
> Simplifying the combinatorials numbers you would get
>
> $${n \choose k_1}{n-k_1 \choose k_2}\cdots {n-k_1-\cdots-k_{n-2} \choose k_{n-1}}{n-k_1-\cdots-k_{n-1} \choose k_n}=\frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!\cdots k_n!}$$
>
> **Note 2**
>
> By the multinomial theorem we know that:
>
> $$(x_1 + x_2  + \cdots + x_n)^n =\sum_{k_1+k_2+\cdots+k_n=n}\frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!\cdots k_n!}x_1^{k_1} x_2^{k_2} \cdots x_n^{k_n}$$
>
> Differentiating with respect to $x_i$ and then respect to $x_j$:
>
> $$n(n-1)(x_1 + x_2  + \cdots + x_n)^{n-2} =\sum_{k_1+k_2+\cdots+k_n=n}k_i k_j\frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!\cdots k_n!}x_1^{k_1} \cdots x_k^{k_i-1}x_j^{k_j-1} \cdots x_n^{k_n}$$
>   $$=\frac{1}{x_i}\frac{1}{x_j}\sum_{k_1+k_2+\cdots+k_n=n} k_i k_j\frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!\cdots k_n!}x_1^{k_1} x_2^{k_2} \cdots x_n^{k_n}$$
>
> Finally:
>
> $$n(n-1)(x_1 + x_2  + \cdots + x_n)^{n-2} x_ix_j=\sum_{k_1+k_2+\cdots+k_n=n} k_ik_j \frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!\cdots k_n!}x_1^{k_1} x_2^{k_2} \cdots x_n^{k_n}$$
>
> Then if $x_k=\frac{1}{n} \ \ \forall i=1..n$
>
> $$\frac{n-1}{n}=\frac{1}{n^n}\sum_{k_1+k_2+\cdots+k_n=n}k_ik_j\frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!\cdots k_n!}x_1^{k_1}x_2^{k_2}\cdots x_n^{k_n}$$